# I noticed only on 2 pages I keep getting permalimks changed with added -2 or -3?

Tags: permalinks

I have seen 'some' explanations, but I stil lcannot fix it and it is frustrating.

I believe the latest 'time' this happened is just after wordpress auto-updated to 4.9.7 [I thought auto was off! ] now I cannot go back to previous version because in the meantime I have worked on it for hours! I do have backups, but I will lose hours of work.

It is so frustrating and having migrated from @drupal'as it is too 'developer' sided, I now am finding out all wordpress 'innate' problems and this is one of them.

After I seemed to have managed to fix all problems, I now have this!

Wasted all afternoon of my day off for nothing.

Phhfff !
Tired now...

ADDITION
Also noticed I cannot delete images and plugins [ even if I can activate/disactivate them!] I have not done anything to installation.

Also I do not have anything in the trash

Comment: Your question is not a question, but more of a rant. What does "I noticed only on 2 pages" actually mean? What 2 pages? Please ask your question properly so that we can understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in general within WordPress there cannot be Posts or Pages (or other post types) with the same slug (name).

Something that a lot of people forget is that after deleting a Post or Page, it still exists. Only after completely removing the entry, is it really gone and can the slug again be used.

So, if you have a Post with the title "Hello world" and the slug "hello-world", then that is unique. If you make a new Post with the same title, the slug will automatically become "hello-world-2".

If you delete the aforementioned Post "Hello world", but you do not empty the Trash, then a new Post  with the same title will again automatically become "hello-world-2".

Only after deleting **and** emptying the Trash can you make a new Post "Hello world" with a slug of "hello-world".

Hope that helps.